# FFmpeg - Max Height (crop)

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible (in cmd batch ffmpeg) to take an image with known width (1920px) but unknown height, and crop the height to something specific if it exceeds? Basically a Max-Height crop.

I've played around with scaling and crop but I cannot get the result I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter with [`min`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation):

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "crop=w=iw:h='min(720,ih)'" output
```

Default behavior is to center the crop. Other examples:

- Crop bottom: `crop=w=iw:h='min(720,ih)':x=0:y=0`
- Crop top: `crop=w=iw:h='min(720,ih)':x=0:y=ow`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! :) and I appreciate the extra info too, I needed the "Crop bottom" example, so thanks again!